# Add a custom WooCommerce settings tab with sections

Tags: php, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, options

I'm trying to add a custom settings tab to the WooCommerce settings screen. Basically I want to achieve a similar thing to the Products settings tab, with the subsections/subtabs:

[image: WooCommerce Products settings tab]

I haven't been able to find any decent documentation on how to do this but I've been able to add a custom tab using this snippet:

```
class WC_Settings_Tab_Demo {

    public static function init() {
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_settings_tabs_array', __CLASS__ . '::add_settings_tab', 50 );
    }

    public static function add_settings_tab( $settings_tabs ) {
        $settings_tabs['test'] = __( 'Settings Demo Tab', 'woocommerce-settings-tab-demo' );
        return $settings_tabs;
    }
}
WC_Settings_Tab_Demo::init();
```

[image: Custom WooCommerce settings tab]

Based on what I've dug up from various threads/tutorials, I've been trying to add the sections/subtabs to the new settings tab something like this:

```
// creating a new sub tab in API settings
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_sections_test','add_subtab' );
function add_subtab( $sections ) {
    $sections['custom_settings'] = __( 'Custom Settings', 'woocommerce-custom-settings-tab' );
    $sections['more_settings'] = __( 'More Settings', 'woocommerce-custom-settings-tab' );
    return $sections;
}


// adding settings (HTML Form)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_settings_test', 'add_subtab_settings', 10, 2 );
function add_subtab_settings( $settings, $current_section ) {
    // $current_section = (isset($_GET['section']) && !empty($_GET['section']))? $_GET['section']:'';
    if ( $current_section == 'custom_settings' ) {
        $custom_settings = array();
        $custom_settings[] = array( 'name' => __( 'Custom Settings', 'text-domain' ),
                                   'type' => 'title',
                                   'desc' => __( 'The following options are used to ...', 'text-domain' ),
                                   'id' => 'custom_settings'
                                  );

        $custom_settings[] = array(
                                    'name'     => __( 'Field 1', 'text-domain' ),
                                    'id'       => 'field_one',
                                    'type'     => 'text',
                                    'default'  => get_option('field_one'),

                                );

        $custom_settings[] = array( 'type' => 'sectionend', 'id' => 'test-options' );
        return $custom_settings;
    } else {
        // If not, return the standard settings
        return $settings;
    }
}
```

I've been able to add new subsections to the Products tab using similar code to the above, but it isn't working for my new custom tab. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: I've closed this for 2 reasons, the first is WooCommerce and other 3rd party product questions are offtopic here. the second is the question was asked at stackoverflow by the author and they recieved and accepted an answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72816886/add-a-custom-woocommerce-settings-page-including-page-sections